# cout does not work as normal user for Visual C++ Express 2010 on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "========================" << "\n" << flush;
    return 0;
}
```

If I build, using Visual Express 2010 in Windows 7, the above code as an administrator and then run the produced executable as normal user in a cmd shell, it prints the expected output.
If I clean and build the same code as a a normal user and then run the produced executable as normal user in a cmd shell, it prints nothing.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: It seems like you asked [a very similar question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939541/visual-c-2010-express-for-win32-project-linking-only-works-as-administrator).

Comment: Yes, but I have not been able to get to the bottom of this problem.

Comment: Without any more details, I dont think anyone can help you.

Comment: Please ask for the details needed. If I knew which way to turn I would have explore it by now. But I am clueless.

Comment: Please explain the exact steps you take to "run the exe in the cmd shell" (Including where the folders are located, etc.).

Comment: Basically, the executable is under the projects Debug folder. I run a cmd shell, cd into the Debug folder and invoke my program.

Comment: Here are more details, as a normal user created the project "TestCout" for console and as an empty project in 
D:\Data\alex\C++\CommonLibs\TestCout folder. I built the project.
As a normal user, I run a Visual Studion 2010 cmd shell; cd into D:\Data\alex\C++\CommonLibs\TestCout\Debug and in there I invoked TestCout.exe. No output displayed.

I then quited the Visual Studio and re-run it as an administrator. Cleaned and rebuilt.

Using the same original cmd shell and in the same folder,  I invoked TestCout.exe. Output displayed correctly.

Comment: It looks to me that the problem is a bug with Visual C++ Express and Windows 7. There is a problem with Studio that it cannnot perform all the tasks when run as a normal user. This is just a gut feeling.

Comment: @Alex : If there were such a bug then I suspect that more people than just you would be affected. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn, Thanks but you never know. I initially had visual express 2005 and 2008 installed (I never got to use these two compilers, because it was in a bran new laptop). Then I proceeded to install visual C++ 2010. After I did that I uninstalled 2005 and 8. Seeing that I was having the problem described this post I proceeded to unsinstall every single visual studio and reinstalled 2010 only. And here I am.

Comment: If you debug and step through the program with VS (started as a normal user), can you step over every line of your main function or does it fail part way through? I only use full VS not express, in the express version do you have the option under the Debug menu for Exceptions. If so, go into here and check the Thrown boxes. That will cause the debugger to stop if any exception occurs... if it does stop, tell us where. And give us the text that appears in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact answer, but I will try to provide assistance.

1) As a normal user, right-click Visual Studio command prompt and and then click Run as administrator. That way you can run Visual Studio as a normal user and only use command prompt as administrator.

2) Your Debug folder location is not the default. I use Visual C++ 2010 Express as a normal user and use the default location /user/visual studio 2010/projects. I can run the program fine with no problems. Also check that you have executable privileges on the file by right clicking it.

Also, why don't you just use "Ctrl+F5" to run the program from the IDE? This way is much faster if you just want to run the program.
One more thing, try opening the cmd shell from outside of Visual Studio, cd into the folder and running it, and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem due to improper rights assigned.
Try giving the normal user the administrative rights. 
Also, check whether the file is in your Documents and not on the C:\program files
Due to in adequate right's you may not be able to modify the settings.
And thus, no debug would take place in the directory prescribed.

Comment: The point here is for a Standard user to be able to use Visual C++, compile and produce a runnable executable. I do not want the user to have administrative rights. 
When you say check your 'file', what file are you referreing to?